# environment variable in ubuntu for java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I have installed oracle java JDK 8 to my new OS (Ubuntu)
but I couldnt find where should I add environment variable like in windows so that I can use java from any where of the system.
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines at the end of the user profiles in the ~/.profile file or, as a superuser, at the end of the global profiles in the /etc/profile file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=<jre installation home directory like /usr/lib/jvm/jrel.8.0>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Logout and login again.